# Biggest Irreducible Cat

Tags: code-bowling

I guess you could call this the next challenge in the "Irreducible series".

- [Hello World](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/196824/biggest-irreducible-hello-world)

## Challenge

Create a [cat](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Cat_program#:%7E:text=The%20cat%20program%20is%20a,every%20program%20is%20a%20quine.) subject to the constraint that it is *irreducible*.

A cat program `C` is considered *irreducible* if there does not exist a cat (in the same programming language as `C`) that can be constructed by removing characters from `C`.

For example

```
console.log(prompt.call());
```

can have the the bracketed characters removed

```
console.log(prompt[.call]())[;] ->
console.log(prompt())
```

And it will still be a cat. Therefore `console.log(prompt.call());` is not irreducible.

The winner will be the program with the longest source code.

## Extras

A big shout out to [@acupoftea](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/90124/acupoftea) for [showing](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/196824/biggest-irreducible-hello-world#comment483918_196824) that, for any given language, there is actually a maximum score. Otherwise you could construct an infinite set that would break [Higman's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higman%27s_lemma)!.

Comment: While this challenge is clear enough to avoid any major issues, I'd *highly* recommend that for later challenges you check out the [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges), even if it's just to get a screen for duplicates before posting. This is *especially* true for winning criteria other than code-golf, which can be difficult to get right, and if not worded properly, can lead to challenge-breaking answers (e.g. infinite scores). (cont)

Comment: (cont) I can't see any major issues with this challenge (partly due to the simplicity of the task, ignoring the scoring criteria), but it's very easy to made a mistake or to misword something, which is what the Sandbox is for.

Comment: Is there reason to expect approaches used here for cat to be different from the earlier Hello World challenge?

Comment: [tag: code- bowling] has long since fallen very, very far out of favour 'round here.

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing thanks for the edit. I didn't see how to link to comments.

Comment: @Shaggy Respectfully, I disagree. If done well, code bowling challenges can be just as fun as code golf, or really any other type of challenge. Rather, code bowling can be a difficult scoring criteria to get right, and so many people avoid it. This challenge, however, is, imo, a good use of code bowling vs any other scoring criteria.

Comment: @xnor I thought so just because you would have to incorporate user input, but maybe I'm wrong. If I'm being honest, I never quite wrapped my head around the more crazy answers last time.

Comment: Also, will there ever be multi-line input? Or will it just be a single line?

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing does that make a difference? Isn't it just a string either way?

Comment: @Mason Some languages will have builtins to take a single line from input, rather than the full input. For example, in Python, `input()` only takes a single line. If the input is multilined, then `input()` wouldn't be sufficient to get all the input

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing is there any trick to have it accept a string with a new line? For example, javascript's `prompt` doesn't let you type a new line via enter, but you can paste a string into that has one.

Comment: @Mason Using `sys.stdin.read()` you can get the full input, but the `input()` builtin doesn't let you. Our [standard cat question](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/62230/simple-cat-program) requires answers to handle newlines, so I'd recommend you do the same

Comment: @Mason, as an example: if it's only ever a single line of input then my solution can be reduced by removing the `qR` at the end.

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing would you recommend I just changed the "cat" linked above to the standard?

Comment: I'm going to vote to close this for now, since it seems all of the answers (besides the Retina one, which doesn't exactly matter since Retina can't exactly evaluate code) are doing the same thing as was effective last time: finding a way to encode a regular version of the program as a number, then converting that number into a string of the code and evaluating it. If you or anyone else comes up with a convincing reason these are different I'll be happy to reopen.

Comment: @Mason I’d recommend clarifying in the question whether the input will have multiple lines or not (which is left ambiguous is the linked esolangs page)

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly) `u`, \$4\times10^{41}\$ bytes

```
“...”WẈbØ%ỌV
```

Except instead of `...` its \$133390687877217192365177139021057049493695\$ `Ɱ` characters

More specifically, a score of \$400172063631651577095531417063171148481103\$

### How it works

The standard cat program in Jelly is

```
ƈȮøL¿
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9Yx4l1h3f4HNr//39uaU5JJldOZl4qV2ZeQWkJAA)

If we convert each of these characters to their Unicode code point we get

```
[392, 558, 248, 76, 191]
```

Treat this a base \$4294967296 = 2^{32}\$ number and convert it back to decimal to get \$133390687877217192365177139021057049493695\$

The above program has a string consisting of \$133390687877217192365177139021057049493695\$ `Ɱ` characters. We then take its length, convert it to base \$4294967296\$, convert back to characters and run as Jelly code.

By forcing Jelly to encode the source as UTF-8 rather than using the Jelly code page, multi byte characters are counted as multiple bytes rather than just 1.

This is 100% irreducible. The cat program it encodes is optimal for Jelly, so there's no way to remove any of the `Ɱ` characters and still create a cat program, and all of the other characters are necessary to correctly convert the string to a program and execute it. More specifically:

- Removing either `“` or `”` will cause syntax errors
- Removing the `W` will cause `Ẉ` to return a list of lists of \$1\$s rather than the code points in base \$4294967296\$
- Removing the `Ẉ` will mean the program won't ever convert the string to the code points in base \$4294967296\$
- Removing any of `bØ%` will prevent the base conversion happening
- Removing `Ọ` or `V` will stop the program from converting to characters and running the program

Furthermore, I believe this is the longest you can get using the method of "long string's length in a high base" in Jelly. The base being used must meet the following criteria:

- The number isn't "constructed" via commands to be larger, as these commands can be removed and the long string adjusted for the lower base
- The number doesn't have digits in it, as characters can be removed to just isolate the lowest digit and the long string can then be adjusted to match this new base

`Ø%` is the largest constant Jelly has which meets these criteria at \$2^{32}\$, so, as a higher base leads to a longer string, an answer in Jelly cannot beat this one.

Comment: I don't see a restriction that the removed characters have to be consecutive, so I think I can reduce this program to `“...”LỌV` (where there are 608 characters in the string).

Comment: @Neil Yeah, I must've missed that in my first read-through :/

Answer (score 5):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/) with `-trigraphs`, <s>327</s> <s>357</s> 413 bytes

Some creative uses of the language:

- Very important `typedef`s for pointers to types
- Constants that are then decremented using the super-experimental [tadpole operator](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20150525-00/?p=45044)
- Dynamic allocation of the character buffer, for reasons
- Use of `fread` to read in a character
- Use of `fprintf` to print a character as a fixed single-byte string
- The essential use of trigraphs in case you are typing on a keyboard from the 1800s
- Using `iso646.h` because the ISO said so :-)

```c
??=include <stdio.h>
??=include <stdlib.h>
??=include <iso646.h>
typedef unsigned*v;struct g??<v c;??>;typedef struct g*h;h c;main()??<c=calloc(sizeof(struct g),-??-EXIT_SUCCESS);c->c=calloc(sizeof(unsigned),-??-EXIT_SUCCESS);do??<fread(c->c,-??-EXIT_SUCCESS,-??-EXIT_SUCCESS,stdin);if(feof(stdin)==EXIT_FAILURE xor EXIT_FAILURE)fprintf(stdout,"%.1s",c->c);??>while(feof(stdin)==EXIT_FAILURE xor EXIT_FAILURE);??>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lZDPS8MwFIDv/hVhIDSjHQiyS9YGGRUHnqwDb1JfkvZBTEqSbuofb20mBel28fi@972fkDUAw8B5jgZ0LyTZ@CDQrtriagY1vs0peru@XUcaPjsppCK98dgYKZYH5oPrIZCG882BAOO8YJM1pZYta8fUe40moaMHOdRaW0g8fkmrksmjacZ5Vr7snl@r/XZbVhVlkBVzfRp@SRd27K@crEUSK8@McxD/YChDlajfXWKY5yfn/m73uH8qyYd15C@gqnNowsm2fUgX16sbv0jjRBo/cGxRy//0i0XD8CDHM8nROi2@Qem68UMWHDau7lr/Aw)

Comment: I just noticed that the highlighter really doesn't know what to do with trigraphs. Bug or feature? :-)

Comment: You can remove the 3 spaces after the 3 `include`s.

Comment: You can remove the `f` in `fprintf` together with the `stdout,` inside.

Answer (score 3):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), <s>11</s> <s>12</s> 15 bytes

```
\A`[^\\](?<=\\)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY0xDsIwDEV3TvE3YEEcAIS4AisB1bSGRqQxil0Kpw8pLHS1338vsflIObt9dTw7d1rsNlvnljkfuJOnjzdYy7j6pAaHRljj3DBIuuPCNfXKX0B6e/Tl7kNAS08GRfDLEiHyEHzk1Wwi3EMSqqmP9F9FYaC3jhHpWLH@E0jBEuqWEtXGSX9ZsgLrOAwyQMsKY7hIpTzQcGDjZvUB) Explanation: The `\` suppresses the trailing newline, without which the program fails to be a cat program. The `` A` `` is required to identify the stage as an AntiGrep rather than a Match stage (which would just output the count of something). For the output to match the input, the pattern must fail to match; this is done by matching any non-`\` and then ensuring that the character was actually a `\`; this character was chosen because it needs to be quoted, making the pattern longer.

I also looked into the other stage types Retina has to see what the best I could do for them was.

- Deduplicate - best I could do was `` \D`() `` (5 bytes) deduplicate all empty strings
- Grep - best I could do was `` \G` `` (3 bytes) keep everything
- Match - best I could do was `` \!`(.|[^.])+ `` (12 bytes) match everything
- Sort - best I could do was `` \O$` `` or `` \O`$ `` or similar (4 bytes) sort in original order or sort nothing
- Replace - best I could do was a single newline (1 byte) replace nothing with nothing - this means that all Retina cat programs that contain a newline can be reduced to 1 byte
- Split - best I could do was `` \S`\n `` (5 bytes) split on newlines and join with newlines
- Transliteration - best I could do was `` \T` `` (3 bytes) translate nothing

Comment: given the answers to the last challenge, I definitely didn't expect to see a submission with 11 bytes XD

Comment: @Mason I was stuck on 5 bytes for quite some time, then clawed my way up to 7 and 10 before eventually reaching the giddy heights of 11!

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES7), 10346554967051525 bytes

The string `-~[]` is actually repeated \$2586638741762875\$ times.

```javascript
Infinity=>eval((-~[]-~[]-~[]-~[]…-~[])**20+'')
```

You can [Try this version online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@98zLy0zL7Ok0tYutSwxR0PDyNTCzMzYwtzE0NzMyMLcQLcuOhYda2ppGRloq6tr/k/OzyvOz0nVy8lP10jTUPJIzcnJV1TS1PwPAA), where all but the last 5 `-~[]` have been replaced with a hard-coded integer.

#### How?

The characters in the name of the input variable `Infinity` are not used anywhere else, so we can't simplify the code by shortening it. The only way to get its content is that the expression in `eval()` evaluates to the string `"Infinity"`.

We do it by computing:

$$2586638741762875^{20}$$

where \$2586638741762875\$:

- is less than [`Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER) and can therefore be generated by adding \$1\$ repeatedly
- becomes higher than [`Number.MAX_VALUE`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_VALUE) when raised to the power of \$20\$

We can probably make it longer by using a more convoluted expression. For instance, I think it should still be irreducible if we use `-~RegExp` instead of `-~[]`.

Comment: Could you make it longer by using `function()` instead of `=>`?

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 125 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

I'm very far from sure that this is valid but I am somewhat sure it can be beaten!

```
Ov"11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111"n2 a"11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111110110001"n2  d  qR
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=T3YiMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTEibjIgYSIxMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMTExMDExMDAwMSJuMiAgZCAgcVI&input=MQoyCjMKNA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <sup><s>8+(10*(85+(10*749535276648396287585636512750330369605831039396714237143337)))</s></sup> infinite bytes

```python
exec("\U0000006e\U0000003d\U00000030\U0000003b\U00000063\U0000003d\U00000022\U00000030\U00000030\U00000030\U00000030\U0000002e\U0000002e\U0000002e\U0000002e\U0000002e\U00000022\U0000000a\U00000066\U0000006f\U00000072\U00000020\U0000005f\U00000020\U00000069\U0000006e\U00000020\U00000063\U0000003a\U0000006e\U0000002b\U0000003d\U00000031\U0000000a\U00000073\U0000003d\U00000062\U00000079\U00000074\U00000065\U00000061\U00000072\U00000072\U00000061\U00000079\U00000028\U00000029\U0000000a\U00000077\U00000068\U00000069\U0000006c\U00000065\U00000020\U0000006e\U0000003a\U00000073\U0000002e\U00000061\U00000070\U00000070\U00000065\U0000006e\U00000064\U00000028\U0000006e\U00000026\U00000032\U00000035\U00000035\U00000029\U0000003b\U0000006e\U0000003e\U0000003e\U0000003d\U00000038\U0000000a\U00000065\U00000078\U00000065\U00000063\U00000028\U00000073\U0000002e\U00000064\U00000065\U00000063\U0000006f\U00000064\U00000065\U00000028\U00000029\U00000029")
```

The `exec("")` adds 8 characters, and unicode-escapes multiply the  count by 10.

Decoded:

```python
n=0;c="\U00000030\U00000030\U00000030\U00000030....."
for _ in c:n+=1
s=bytearray()
while n:s.append(n&255);n>>=8
exec(s.decode())
```

This decoding routine adds the 85 characters.

The string inside `c` is the actual code, encoded in unary, with a unicode-escaped `0` character per unary digit.

This is too large to fit in the observable universe (approximately $$7.5  \times 10 ^ {60}$$ characters long), hence no TIO link.

The unary is then decoded and executed, to get a `cat` program:

```python
while True:print(input())
```

I'm pretty sure you could recursively repeat these steps *ad infinitum* and it would still be irreducible (so I win by default), but I thought I'd keep my answer as an example finite.

Comment: Given that a proof has been found that every language has a maximum finite score, it would appear as though your program cannot be increased ad infinitum and that at some point it reaches a point where it’s no longer irreducible. My guess would be that if you attempt to encode the `exec('...')` in the same manner, you’d be able to remove a subset from `...` to reduce it back down to the original `exec(...)` form.

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing to be honest I've not tried very hard to work out if the unary part is reducible

Comment: I don't think you can claim the 10* for the Unicode escapes of digits; `\U00000038` can be reduced to `8` for example.