# The longest "Hello World!" program

Tags: hello-world

I was seen multiple shortest "Hello World!" program, but this is the **longest** program.

**The Rules**

- Each submission must be a full program.
- This must be non-interpreted language (for example, JavaScript, Python, HTML, etc.)
- Target OS must be Windows, Mac, Linux or MS-DOS.

**The challenge**

- Writing a **longest** Hello World program.

Comment: Do you mean a interpreted language? All languages you list are interpreted

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Biggest Irreducible Hello World](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/196824/92901).

Comment: @Dingus No, it contains the Python, JavaScript, which is listed as interpreted.

Comment: Well, Python is *technically* compiled, so...

Comment: @SuperStormer In what sense?

Comment: It compiles to bytecode before executing that @RydwolfPrograms If you consider that compiled is up to interpretation

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! I'd recommend using the [sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges) for future challenges; this one has a lot of issues. For example, what keeps me from adding a comment or a string literal or a variable name or whitespace that takes up terabytes of space? It's trivially possible to get an arbitrarily large score right now. Also, [tag:restricted-time] is about runtime, not a time limit for submissions.

Comment: You listed Python and JavaScript as example languages but then tagged it [tag:c]. Furthermore as already mentioned JavaScript *is* an interpreted language. What's the intention here?
Note also that as per the tag description, "challenges that require the answers to be in a specific language are generally discouraged."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/) (little-endian), 9,624,671,272,932,611,623 bytes

```c
#include<string.h>
main(){char x[14];long i,j;/* i++; repeated 2406167339672739884 times */ /* j++; repeated 478560413000 times */memcpy(x,&j,8);memcpy(x+5,&i,8);puts(x);}
```

[Try an equivalent version online!](https://tio.run/##PcjdCsIgGADQ@55iEAwlC51OHbZeJLoYNtwn0439gBE9u9FNl@fYs7M25yNEO@7P/rpuC0R3GW6H0EFE@G2HbinSnYmHGafoCiDeQFsJKplUnDdSVYo3WgvjW6F0LalgnFJqQh/s/EKJlJ5o/OepJiX8Yt63FSVsPjl/AQ/##VcrdCoIwGIDh867ig0D8WTnd3CaLbiQ6kDl04pboBCO69lUHBR2@L486dEqFsDdOjWurT4ufjeuO/XlnG@Pi5KH6ZobtUtCrHG@uA4MGmadgskzCrCfdeN1CSTErGCekZrzkpBaCgjdWL5Dm8NbDn6ZcVAzTgmCMf8xqq6Z7vKFoQCKR38wqFJnPmFa/xFsinyG8AA)

For some reason I can't post the full program, so it has been abbreviated in the comments.

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf!